# react-daterange-picker enable only on button click

Tags: react-datepicker, react-datetime, react-daterange-picker

In Date range picker i can disable it completly but i am unable to disable only input range date's in picker.

If possible not possible kindly please suggest a way to do it.

[Disable input range enable button click range picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRyn1.png)

```
<DateRangePicker onChange={handleDateChange} value={value} format="dd MMM yy" className='datePickerStyle' disabled="true" />
```